# rspec with dashing in ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, dashing

I have the below code in my `index_spec.rb`

```
require '../../spec_helper'
    describe "Dashboards" do
      describe "Welcome Widget" do
        it "should have the content" do
          visit '../../dashboards/index'
          page.should have_content('Random Content.')
        end
      end
    end
```

i ran `rspec index_spec.rb` and it failed saying `'unidentified method visit'`, then i searched on the net and included the following in the `spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'capybara'
include Capybara::DSL
```

when i include it, it shows me " `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end`" at `spec_helper.rb: 1`, i have been trying this out for last three hours, could not figure out where i need to put 'end' in the spec_helper file. Let me know if some worked on dashing and validated the dashboard file using rspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add `capybara` to your Gemfile and bundle it. Then add to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Also

```
# change this:
# visit '../../dashboards/index'
# to:
visit dashboard_path
```

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec

Comment: i included the capybara gem in my gemfile. "gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'". but it still shows no visit method identified. Also, whenever i change anything in my rspec file, for example, if it has two 'requires' or even two lines, it throws an error that it cannot find 'end'.